# AWS Fargate windows container fails to start with "Task failed to start"

Tags: amazon-web-services, dockerfile, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am trying to run a dotnet windows service on ECS Fargate. I setup the infrastructure with CloudFormation.
When the task leaves pending state, it fails with the message below:

[image: ECS Fargate Task Error]

In the dockerfile, I added a sleep.ps1 script to keep the container up in while running in Fargate:

[image: Command to run Wake Script]

The sleep script:

[image: Wake Script]

My sleep script did not work, I need help keeping the task running on Fargate.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, I added the below command to the dockerfile:

ENTRYPOINT ["powershell.exe"];

CMD ["C:/temp/Scripts/sleep.ps1"]